# Irrigation pressure vacuum assembly leaking

Tags: leak, water-pressure, irrigation

I am trying to dewinterize my sprinkler system the first time in a home we moved into. After turning on the water to it from the basement, the pressure vacuum assembly just outside the house was leaking:

[image: vacuum assembly]

I'm totally new to this, but I understand from some YouTube videos that there's something I need to turn to pressurize this assembly. In most videos it is a ball valve or screw, but I don't see anything like that here. There is that spinning thing nearby, but I'm not sure what it's for.

Any ideas how to dewinterize this?

Here is a closeup on the gold lip:

[image: gold lip]

There are model numbers there but they don't return anything on a Web search.

Ken

Comment: Is the water coming from around the gold part at the top?  Or somewhere else?  If it’s somewhere else then you have a broken pipe from a freeze where water wasn’t drained from the assembly last fall. If it’s from the lip of the gold part then see if you can determine make/model of the valve.  The valve you’re referring to is the valve you turned on inside.

Comment: Hi Tyson, I've added a closeup with the gold part. There are model numbers there but a Web search doesn't return anything helpful.

Comment: Try: http://www.watts.com/pages/search.asp?keyword=288a&x=39&y=15

Comment: It’s discontinued replaced by LF288A-DM

Comment: do you realize that `pressure` and `vacuum` are mutually exclusive terms ... that is a `vacuum breaker`

Comment: Actually it’s available on amazon, for some reason my link won’t paste but type 288a into amazon search.

Comment: Tyson, thanks for the links. So are you saying it's broken and needs to be replaced? I thought I just needed to find the right valve to turn, as in the YouTube videos.

Comment: By the way, I should have mentioned that yes, water is definitely coming from the gold part at the top. Until that stops running, it will be hard to tell if water is coming from anywhere else as well. jsotola, thanks for setting me straight on the right language. I am new to this. Should I try turning the spinner to the lower left of this gold part?

Comment: If it’s not sealing anymore, yes it needs to be replaced.  It might have a replaceable seal, I can’t tell... a plumbing supply house would more than likely have the seal, if it’s available, or it might be better to replace the whole unit.  It may have been ice damaged, I can’t tell from your picture how it was intended to drain this for winter, I’m guessing it wasn’t done correctly last fall.

Comment: it is not a valve that you can adjust .... it prevents backflow of water from the irrigation pipes into the city water supply .... if city pressure drops because of broken water main downhill from you, the water in the city main will reverse direction and start siphoning water from houses ... if that happens, then the vacuum breaker will let in air instead of sucking water from the irrigation pipes (the sprinkler could be submerged in a puddle and contaminated water would get into the city supply)

Comment: jsotola and Tyson, thank you! I will order the replacement, but one last question first. What about the red spin valve on the other side of the vacuum breaker? I was thinking of closing that red spin valve and then turning the water back on to see if I can "repressurize" the vacuum breaker. I saw something like this in a YouTube video about dewinterizing sprinklers. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's one more for Tyson. In one comment you mentioned the 288A-DM. Don't you mean the 288A, without the "DM"? The DM is the deck-mounted model. It appears to be for washing machines, but I'm not an expert. Also, in my viewing of the picture, I don't see "DM." Am I correct?

Comment: Yea I did make a mistake, no DM.  BTW... put @ in front of a name if it’s for a person, the @ will notify that person to read the comment... you got lucky this time.. I just happen to come back)